# CLI filesystem benchmark for random read/write with specified block size

Tags: linux, filesystems, benchmark

I'm in search of a filesystem benchmark utility. I basically want to run a test which should be able to do random reads/writes on a specified drive with a given block size. e.g. a 4K random write on a linux system.

Comment: Were you ever able to track down a utility which did what you wanted it to do?

Answer (score 4):

Check the [Linux Benchmark Suite](http://lbs.sourceforge.net/) page. It has links to a bunch of benchmarks, including [bonie](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/bonnie/) and [bonie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) which can do what you want (and more).

For bonnie++, to change the block size, you might also need to specify the test file size.

```
usage: bonnie++ [-d scratch-dir] [-s size(MiB)[:chunk-size(b)]]
```

So `bonnie++ ... -s 1g:4k ...` should do I/O in 4096 byte chunks.

Also check out [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/). It has a scary number of command line arguments, but `r` can be used to fix the block size. Check out the documentation to understand the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but neither bonnie nor the programms on the Linux Benchmark Suite (been there, done that) are able to do random write/reads with 4K Chunk size. I found IOtest, which is exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately there is no working download link on the company's page.

Comment: I was pretty sure it could. Did you try the `-s size:chunk-size` option?

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, I tried bonnie++ with the chunk-size and this is the output: http://dpaste.com/587091/ As you can see, it only displays random create per second and delete per second. I'm looking for a tool with a output like this: http://lwn.net/Articles/220277/

Answer (score 4):

These days [`fio`](https://github.com/axboe/fio) would do that very easily:

```
fio --name=basic --filename=/mnt/fs/fiotestfile --size=1G --rw=randrw --bs=4k
```

See the [fio documentation](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a description of fio's (many) options.

Comment: Depending on what one wants to accomplish with the mixed r/w test, it might be interesting to specify the percentages of reads and writes with `--rwmixread=90` (for 90% reads for example) and to ignore any caching (`--direct=1`). The default mix is 50/50 which is quite unrealistic for most work loads IMHO.